# EF model mapping multiple databases

Tags: entity-framework

I have a model in my project that maps to a LOT of views in my database, but I need to map to a view in another database.

How can I do this? Do I have to create another model? I don't want to, but I will if I have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same model can't get data from the two different DBs. The easiest way would be to create a view in the same database that calls and returns data from the other database i.e. the abstraction view that internally calls external DB view.

Comment: Oh how I would love to make a view with data from the other db. In fact, I wanted to do that, but I've been told that possibility is forbidden for me. :P

Answer (score 2):

If your database supports synonyms, you could setup a synonym to the other database, and merge the edmx definition in with your 1st database's definition. I wrote how to do it [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/tricking-ef-to-span-multiple-databases/)

Basically you end up with two edmx files, and a script that merges the two into a working edmx file. Synonyms are used to reference one database from the other without needing the full database path.

Answer (score 0):

If you use code first approach in Entity Framework, here is how to map EF entity to the table from other database:

SQL Script that needs to be run in your database to create  synonym for the table from other database:

```
CREATE SYNONYM OtherDatabaseTableSynonym FOR otherdatabase.dbo.otherdatabasetable
```

Entity Framework Mapping in (Fluent API):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OtherDatabaseTableEntity>().ToTable("OtherDatabaseTableSynonym").HasKey(x => x.id);
```